# Can you confirm this is not possible to easily "list and select" a printer from an Android app?

Tags: android, printing

Being not used to Android native development, I'd need a confirmation that **listing and selecting an already-configured Printer** (already configured through my Android System Printing Service) is not achievable **directly from within an Android App**.

My main objective is to allow to reference a printer "once for all" in my Android app which is going to run on a free access Tablet, aimed at staying on the same network where resides the printer. I would like to prevent Users from having the possibility to select by themselves the printer they want to print their document to.

It appears that Android is "sandboxing" this part, relying on a system-based Print Dialog, when we either call the [`PrinterDiscoverySession`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrinterDiscoverySession) from a [`PrintService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintService), or rely on [`PrintDocumentAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.html)
Thus not allowing to gain access to any `PrinterInfo` / `PrinterId` list programmatically.

[image]

Can you confirm that I didn't missed something important ?

Note : by "easily" (in the title) I mean without re-implementing low level communication between the device and the printer. Rather relying on some Android SDK to achieve this.